# Need to load property file using absolute path and classloader

Tags: java, classloader, absolute-path

So i have a 3rd party class, (company mandate to use it), which exposes one static method called

public static Properties loadProperty(String path) ;

Internally it tries to load using following code.

```
ClassLoader a = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
if (a != null) {
    URL u = a.getResource(path); // - - - > returns null
    if (u != null) {
        u = a.getResource('/' + path); // - - - > returns null
    }

    if (u == null) {
        ClassLoader b = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        u = b.getResource(path); // - - - > returns null

        if (u != null) {
            u = b.getResource('/' + path); // - - - > returns null
        }
    }
}
```

Here problem is, i always gets null.

If i keep the file in /resources and then refer it then it finds the file.

After some research, i found that it refers to relative path.

As my app would be running on different environments, i wanted to make it configurable and keep the file as an external file.

Thus is there a way i can pass a path which will allow the loader to load the files from the path?
Something as 'cd..' goes one step up in directory, is there Any way to go to root(windows - C:\ n Unix root ~) directly and then start from there and go to absolute path?

Appericiate the help.

Comment: Instead, you can have different property files for each environment. During deployment, you can just copy the correct environment property file to the one used by app or you can have placeholders in the main file for the environment specific one and use some config to copy the correct environment specific file.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassLoader`s only load resources that are on the classpath. When dealing with absolute paths to files, one can use the `File` class to access those.

Comment: Thanks @ohlec, so is there a way I can add multiple classpath to load properties? I tried adding using command line -classpath, but it seems to be working only for loading jars.

Comment: You can certainly use -classpath and the load relative to that path; however, this seems very much like abusing the classloader. Why not just read from a `File` directly, given you already know the absolute path?

Comment: I agree, however the problem is, it's an encrypted file and we have inhouse jar available for processing it. This jar only loads from resource folder (or i assumed that after seeing source code as mentioned in question). And it works fine when i put file in resource folder. But i feel that defeats the purpose of properties file. In case i need to change the content, I'll have to create and redeploy the entire jar, that's why was looking out for making it ecternalized.

Comment: So you pass a resource path to your decryption library? In that case, maybe you can add the directory where the file will be found to the classpath and then load it relative to that